# Multiple Price for same product in commerce kickstart?

Tags: commerce

I have installed [Commerce kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart). I have add the products. 
Now my client asked Same product have two different prices. User will choose the price and pay it.

I am trying [Commerce Donate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) also.This module price for every product.

I need to change the price value for every product.

[image: Refer the screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well jump all in using [Commerce Customizable Products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) and use this [screencast](https://vimeo.com/31460419) to walk yourself through adding a line item type and a field to set the price.